# Spring security with xml config NoSuchBeanDefenitionException No Qualifying bean of type AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am pretty new to spring. I have met the problem with starting my spring security. 
Here are my XML's and Classes:
web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>   </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>   </listener>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   </servlet>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> </filter>   <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>   </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mobilecompany.controllers, com.mobilecompany.services,
                                            com.mobilecompany.dao"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobilecompany"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="sergio123"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mobilecompany"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.mobilecompany.controllers, com.mobilecompany.services,
                                            com.mobilecompany.dao"/>

         <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/resources/"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/account"
                       access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/adminPanel/**"
                       access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>


        <form-login login-processing-url="/login"
                    login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
                    authentication-failure-url="/"
                    username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password"/>

        <logout logout-success-url="/user/login?logout"/>

        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
                class="com.mobilecompany.services.impl.UsersDetailsServiceImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

SecurityService

```
@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityServiceImpl(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userDetailsServiceImpl = userDetailsServiceImpl;
    }

    @Override
    public String findLoggedInEmail() {

        Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                .getPrincipal();
        if(userDetails instanceof UserDetails)
            return ((UserDetails) userDetails).getUsername();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void autoLogin(String email, String parole) {

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(email);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, parole, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

        if(authenticationToken.isAuthenticated()){
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UsersDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {


    public UsersDetailsServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {
        UsersDao usersDao = new UsersDaoImpl();
        Users user = usersDao.getByEmail(email);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRoles().getName()));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.
                User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

And here is my sstack trace

```
17-Jul-2018 02:44:12.613 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Java Projects\javaschool\target\javaschool\WEB-INF\classes\com\mobilecompany\services\impl\SecurityServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5363)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1730)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    ... 60 more
```

What i am doing wrong? I google it and couldn't find any solution, suitable for me. Help please.

Comment: Not sure but could you please try 
 <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
...

in your spring-security.xml. Perhaps i am wrong.. but it is a fast check

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line in the log :
Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl'

I think its because your implementation of constructor.

Look at this part:

```
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

@Autowired
public SecurityServiceImpl(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.userDetailsServiceImpl = userDetailsServiceImpl;
}
```

Change it to :

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

public SecurityServiceImpl() {
}
```

And test it again. I hope this help you.